# Converting byte array to jpeg image in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, ashx

I have an asp.net page.

Inside this page I have an img control/element.

I am calling an ashx page on my server.

This ashx page accepts a timestamp from the client and compares it to a timestamp stored on the server.

If the timestamps do not match then I return an image which has been converted to a byte array (in C#).

If the timestamps do not match then I return a string value of "-1".

So, this is a cut-down of my ashx page:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    try
    {
        string clientTS = context.Request.QueryString["clientTS"];

        if (clientTS == serverTS)
        {
            //new version available.  refresh browser
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
            string value = "-1";
            context.Response.Write(value);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
            byte[] data = Shared.GetMobileNextFrame("par1", 0);
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(data);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
        context.Response.Write("ERR");
    }
}
```

And in my javascript code:

```
function GetImageStatus() {
    finished = false;
    var val = url + '/Mobile/isNewFrame.ashx?Alias=' + Alias + '&CamIndex=' + camIndex + '&Version=' + version + '&GuidLogOn=' + guidLogOn;
    $.ajax({
        url: val,
        type: 'GET',
        timeout: refreshWaitlimit,
        data: lastTS,
        success: function (response, status, xhr) {
            var ct = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type");
            if (ct.indexOf('json') > -1) {
                //no update
            }
            else {
                try {
                    live1x4.src = 'data:image/bmp;base64,' + encode(response);
                }
                catch (err) {
                    alert(err);
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          //handle error
        }
    });
}

function encode(data) {
    var str = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, data);
    return btoa(str).replace(/.{76}(?=.)/g, '$&\n');
}
```

But I get an error returned:

> TypeError:  Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type

If I just apply:

```
live1x4.src = 'data:image/bmp;base64,' + btoa(response);
```

instead of:

```
live1x4.src = 'data:image/bmp;base64,' + encode(response);
```

I get this error:

> InvalidCharacterError: btoa failed.  the string to be encoded contains
>   characters outside of the Latin1 range.

I have tried using a canvas control with example code i have found on this site. I do not get an error but I also do not get an image.

I know the image is valid because my old code was point the image.src directly to the ashx handler (and i was not comparing timestamps).

I do not want to encode the byte array to base64 string on the server because that would inflate the download data.

I was wondering if I was using the wrong context.Response.ContentType but I could not see what else I could use.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking at the [documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) you should pass 1 or more parameters to `fromCharCode`. You pass none in this line:

> var str = String.**fromCharCode**.apply(null, data);

The syntax is:

```
String.fromCharCode(num1, ..., numN)
```

There is although the `apply` method as your said in comments, but you use it the wrong way. The first parameter shouldn't be `null`.

The syntax of that is (from [Convert array of byte values to base64 encoded string and break long lines, Javascript (code golf)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366727/convert-array-of-byte-values-to-base64-encoded-string-and-break-long-lines-java)):

```
somefunction.apply(thisObj[, argsArray])
```

Just use

```
var str = String.fromCharCode.apply(data);
```

So use the `thisObj` parameter to pass the `data`.

Comment: hi, thanks for taking the time to look at this.  I got that code from a previous StackOverFlow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366727/convert-array-of-byte-values-to-base64-encoded-string-and-break-long-lines-java

Comment: I have not got a clue what I should be using instead of null though

Comment: I admit I may not be thinking clearly here.  I have changed to this:         live1x4.src = 'data:image/bmp;base64,' + encode(response);                          function encode(d) {
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(d);
}                                                                                      I assume this is not what you meant? How should I code it pls?

Comment: You have to keep the `return btoa` line, but change the line above it.

Comment: Hi, I have changed it to this:                                    function encode(d) {
    var str = String.fromCharCode.apply(d);
    return btoa(str).replace(/.{76}(?=.)/g, '$&\n');
}                                                                             I do not get an image though. When I inspect the element via Chrome I get this : <img alt="" id="live1x4" src="data:image/bmp;base64," style="width: 99%; height: 546px;">                                      I may need to think of  different approach. Thank you so much for your time

Comment: I have been trying and trying to get this working, but I have no clue at the moment.

Comment: Another small comment: you use `data:image/bmp` while the type returned from the service is `image/jpg`.

Comment: Hi,  yes I have tried changing bmp to jpeg but it did not make a difference unfortuntaley

Comment: @AndrewSimpson: I know, just to avoid problems later on.