# how to pass value from javascript to hidden field

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

hi i have a javascript method which is reading byte array from applet class i want to put that byte array into request scope to pass the controller class. for that i created one hidden filed and here my doubt is how can i pass that byte array from java script method to hidden field can any body give the solution.

here is my jsp class.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var a="image";
        function printIt(){
            a=document.getElementById('string').value;
        }
        </script>

        <form name="formName" action="second.jsp">
            <input type="hidden" value='a' name="name" id="string"/>
            <input type="submit" id="abcId" name="abcName" onsubmit="printIt()"
                    value="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using Jquery? `$("#string").val(a);` to add the value to the field with an ID of `string`

Comment: look at my answer bellow if as you tagged jquery in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can try to use jquery code to achieve this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#abcId').on('click', function()
 {

     var a="image";
     $('#string').val(a); //<-- this code will take a variable as value an assign it into hidden input

     $('#formID').submit();

 }
</script>
```

HTML code

```
<form name="formName" action="second.jsp" id="formID">
  <input type="hidden" value='a' name="name" id="string"/>
  <input type="submit" id="abcId" name="abcName" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**With jquery**

you want to get the value of your hidden field and set it with return value of the function that is getting the byte array like

```
$("#string").val(functionThatReturnTheByteArray())
```

then you want to submit the form with the hidden field

```
$("form[name='formName']").submit()
```

this will submit the form with the hidden field containing your byte array.

**Summary**

```
$("#string").val(functionThatReturnTheByteArray())
$("form[name='formName']").submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to string-encode your byte-array in order to be able to send it using the request. This might help here: [Convert array of byte values to base64 encoded string and break long lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366727/).
Afterwards you can assign it using

```
document.getElementById('string').value = encode(yourData);
```

Hope that helps.