# Web app to display image from S3 using AWS policy

Tags: html, amazon-s3, frontend, amazon-cognito

### Background

- We have a web app that uses aws-sdk for JavaScript to allow login with AWS Cognito.
- We want to allow user access to files on S3 based on AWS policy.
- Using `AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(...)` we were able to perform a login, and receive a token
- Using this token we perform `listObject` on the bucket.

### The problem

After a successful login and `listObject` on S3, when setting the `src` attribute of a `<img />` tag to `https://MY_BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/my_file.jpg` we get:

`403 (Forbidden)`

It seems that the client request header does not contain the aws-token retrieved by aws-sdk.

### What we've tried

- Going through the Prerequisite Tasks in [this article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html)
- Going through [these examples](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-authentication-part-3-roles-and-policies/)
- [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32702431/display-images-fetched-from-s3) from StackOverflow (yields `Maximum call stack size exceeded`). Besides, it seems like a client side CPU intensive solution.

### The question

What is the cleanest and easiest way to use `CognitoIdentityCredentials` to allow display of images from S3 bucket inside a web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create policy with IAM like so:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html

The Javascript SDK helps get credentials, cache them, and is a wrapper around Cognito APIs. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html#JavaScript

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that when we set the `src` attribute of the `<img />` tag, the outgoing request from the client doesn't have the aws-token in the header.

Comment: @Michael Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: @RetoAebersold I did something as mentioned in the response. You need to get the image from S3 using Cognito, then load it into the img.